# Unable to bind json result to MVC UI

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to bind Json result to MVC 4.0 UI (cshtml) but looks like I am missing something...
Below are my controller and CSHtml page code snippet...

Could you please give me some pointers? as what I am missing or doing wrong ?

Please note that I am able to view the Json result (all rows) when I run the application... only thing is that it is not getting displayed per formatting mentioned below.

Sample of Json on UI that is getting displayed.

```
{"SomeCollection":[{"SequenceID":1,"Name":"test","LastName":"test2","SomeCollection":[]}
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult ShowJsonResult()
{
  return Json(new { objSrv.SomeCollection }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

CSHtml page

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.SmName>
@{
  Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>ShowJsonResult</title>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      //$('#btnGetPersons').click(function ()//{
        $.getJSON("/Server/ShowJsonResult", null, function (data) {
          var div = $('#ajaxDiv');
          div.html("<br/> " + " testing: " + "<br/>");
          $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            printPerson(div, item);
          });
        });
      //});
    });

    function printPerson(div, item) {
      div.append("<br/>" + "Name: " + item.Name);
      $.each(item.Addresses, function (i, addr) {
        printAddress(div, addr);
     });
    }

    function printAddress(div, item) {
      div.append("<br/>" + "   " + "Line1: " + item.Name);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="ajaxDiv"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$.each(item.Addresses, function ..`? Your JSON does not indicate you have a property named `Addresses`. What does `new { objSrv.SomeCollection }` do? Does it initialize and set some properties?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with JSON object.The JSON that you have given cannot be parsed properly or not in correct format.Please recheck and try.